# How to get all the users in xmpp / ejabber using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xmpp, ejabberd

I know how get users from console but i do not know how to write its Ruby code so I can get all the users in my website.

**Get all registered users:**

```
    sudo ejabberdctl registered_users domain_name
```

**Get all online users:**

```
    sudo ejabberdctl connected_users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ejabberd ModRest module for that.

```
url = URI.parse('http://localhost:5285/rest')
@client = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
request = prepare_request(Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri))
request.body = "registered_users #{hostmachine}"
res = @client.request(request).body
```